# Determining which of my two fit functions is better (python)

Tags: fitting

I am working on a python project right now, and it entails me fitting Gaussian curves with either a one component fit or a two component fit. Sometimes, the data just doesn't have two components in it, and I would like to know if there is a statistical test(s) that I can do to that would tell me whether or not the second component is warranted. I'm iterating over >1000 data sets, so it can't just be done visually. I'm really after a test that will tell me if adding the second component helps the goodness of fit. I have three lists to work with for each data set: the data, the one component fit values, and the two component fit values. I've been trying to figure out using p-values or ANOVA, but so far I'm getting results that don't make any sense, which tells me I obviously just don't understand statistics and/or the functions well enough. Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: It is an unfortunate reality that a second component is *always* possible and statistically significant: just focus it closely on a single data value and fit the first component to all other data values. It therefore helps to be more restrictive, such as imposing a nontrivial lower bound on the weights of the components.

Comment: What do you mean that you are "getting results that don't make any sense"?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case for a likelihood ratio test, from which you could apply Wilk's theorem $-2LR \sim \Xi^2_d$ where $d$ is the difference in the number of degrees of freedom between the two models, and LR is the natural log of the ratio of the likelihoods of the two models.

Here, your model with 1 Gaussian would have 2 parameters, the mean and variance of the one Gaussian used to describe the data.

The model with 2 Gaussians would have 5 parameters; the two means, the two variances, and the ratio of the probability mass in one Gaussian versus the other.